# RecyclerView data doesn't show

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView, but data doesn't show in it. 
I tried using the `notifydatasetchange()` but that didn't help and RecyclerView didn't update.

Here is my code :

Adapter class

```
public class Price_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Price_Adapter.viewHolder> {

    private Context mctx;
    private List<Price_Model>modelList;

    public Price_Adapter(Context mctx, List<Price_Model> modelList) {
        this.mctx = mctx;
        this.modelList = modelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mctx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pricelist_row,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        Price_Model price_model = modelList.get(position);
        holder.item.setText(price_model.getItem());
        holder.price.setText(price_model.getPrice());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView item,price;
        private CheckBox checkBox;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        }
    }
}
```

Model Class:

```
public class Price_Model {

    private String item, price;

    public Price_Model() {
    }

    public Price_Model(String item, String price) {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Main code:

```
    pricelist_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_pricelist);
    pricelist_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    pricelist_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
    pricelist_recyclerView.setAdapter(price_adapter);
    priceModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    price_adapter = new Price_Adapter(getActivity(),priceModelList);

    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
```

I am getting this error in my Logcat:

```
2020-05-23 14:53:33.238 1736-1736/? E/chooseup.barbe: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2020-05-23 14:53:34.996 1736-1736/com.chooseup.barber E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
2020-05-23 14:53:34.996 1736-1736/com.chooseup.barber E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-1s637ms what=110 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{d5a0e0e com.chooseup.barber}} } , cost  = 1636 ms
2020-05-23 14:53:34.996 1736-1736/com.chooseup.barber E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
2020-05-23 14:53:35.005 1736-1736/com.chooseup.barber E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-1s636ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl }
2020-05-23 14:53:35.005 1736-1736/com.chooseup.barber E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-587ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl }
2020-05-23 14:53:35.005 1736-1736/com.chooseup.barber E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
2020-05-23 14:53:35.007 1736-2486/com.chooseup.barber E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.chooseup.barber
2020-05-23 14:53:35.008 1736-2486/com.chooseup.barber E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-05-23 14:53:35.009 1736-2486/com.chooseup.barber E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.chooseup.barber
2020-05-23 14:53:35.009 1736-2486/com.chooseup.barber E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Answer (score 0):

No you did not call notifyDataSetChanged()

```
public Price_Adapter(Context mctx, List<Price_Model> modelList) {
    this.mctx = mctx;
    this.modelList = modelList;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged(); // should be present here
}
```

Also, you should initialize your adapter after setting up the values of the list.

Change this code

```
    pricelist_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_pricelist);
    pricelist_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    pricelist_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
    pricelist_recyclerView.setAdapter(price_adapter);
    priceModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    price_adapter = new Price_Adapter(getActivity(),priceModelList);

    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
    priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
```

To this

```
pricelist_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_pricelist);
pricelist_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
pricelist_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));

priceModelList = new ArrayList<>();
priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
priceModelList.add(new Price_Model("rytdfy","fhf"));
// this should be intialized here
price_adapter = new Price_Adapter(getActivity(),priceModelList);
pricelist_recyclerView.setAdapter(price_adapter);
```